# Convex hull solving using a rubber band?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

The convex hull can be found by stretching a rubber band so that it contains all the points and then releasing it.

So my question is : lets assume that we have a robot (a theoretical robot) to solve this problem.
We give it the coordinates of our points ( we have n points ) .

1. It uses some pins to indicate the points in a board (O(n)).
2. Now we choose a point (it's not important which one we choose) then we check its distance with other points like ( sqr( x^2 + y^2 ) ) . And we find the Max distance .
3. Then the robot uses a rubber band and extends it in form of a circle with a radius of distance we found in step 2 and centered in the point we chose in step 2. And it releases the band .
4. Then the robot needs to follow the rubber band to find the vertices of the convex hull in O( m ) where m is the vertices that convex hull consists of them.(m <= n)

so the totall order of the algorithem (this way) would be O(n).

i know i did not take into account the time the rubber band needs to strech or the time it needs for the contraction.

but assuming we have lots of points it (contraction/streching)  takes much less than O(n).

is there anyway to simulate the effect of the rubber band in computer?

i know the lowest possible order for convex hull is said to be O(nlg(n)) due to the sorting lower band .

Comment: It's a bit unclear how the properties of the rubber band would be represented algorithmically. How would the robot find the vertices of the convex hull polygon? By observing that the direction of the polygon lines changes?

Comment: So you are not talking about the robot algorithm here (the fact that it's a robot is irrelevant if I got it right?), but about utilizing the fact that the rubber band creates the hull "for free"? No, this step *is* the actual algorithm, you cannot get this without any computing effort.

Comment: but in the example the rubber band does not do any cumputation does it?

Comment: Yes, it does. Each point in the rubber band is constantly applying tension in the other points.

Comment: then how can we compute the time complexity of the rubber bands computation ?

Comment: i think it must have something to do with parallel computing since the rubber bands tention cahanges simultaniusly in nall the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you *could* emulate that "rubber band algorithm" using some sort of optimization algorithms, but it will probably be horribly slow. Keep in mind that in a sense, the physical world is a gigantic, immensely complex computer, all the time figuring out complex stuff such as gravity, magnetic force, etc., and last but not collision-detection.

First, let's do the setup:

- the rubber band is represented as a doubly-linked list of nodes holding the position of each "atom" in the rubber band (thinking of the rubber band as a 1-d chain of atoms)
- the pins are represented by some sort of spatial map, or very fine-grained n-dimensional array holding the information of whether some small region contains a pin or not

Now, the actual algorithm:

- whenever an "atom" in the rubber band touches/is very near to a pin (according to the spatial map, or n-d array) that atom is fixed and can no longer move
- for all other atoms, slightly alter their positions in order to minimize the distances to their respective adjacent neighbours; you could do this with, e.g., a stochastic optimization or a swarm algorithms
- repeat until all the atoms have "settled down"

Of course, the complexity of this algorithm is terrible, and far worse than *O(n)* or even *O(nlogn)*, because all the expensive computation of the "rubber band" is usually performed be that great physics engine called the universe. (You could probably achieve a similar result by entering the "rubber band and board of pins" problem into any modern physics simulation.)

Answer (score 2):

"is there anyway to simulate the effect of the rubber band in computer": no, not as regards computational complexity. A computer operation handles a constant number of operands at a time. For instance, typical convex hull algorithms take the points three by three and check whether they form a clockwise or counterclockwise triangle. This is said to be done in constant time.

Releasing the band involves all N points and cannot be implemented as a primitive operation.

If you try to somehow emulate it with a computer, you can be sure that it will take at least O(N Log(N)) operations. Anyway, in a discrete universe (integer coordinates), O(N) could be possible using radix sort.

Answer (score 1):

> but assuming we have lots of points it takes much less than O(n).

No it doesn't, because of this step:

> Now we choose a point (it's not important which one we choose) then we check its distance with other points like ( sqr( x^2 + y^2 ) ) . And we find the Max distance .

You cannot find this max distance in less than `O(n)`.

Also:

> Then the robot uses a rubber band and extends it in form of a circle with a radius of distance we found in step 2 and centered in the point we chose in step 2. And it releases the band .
>
> Then the robot needs to follow the rubber band to find the vertices of the convex hull in O( m ) where m is the vertices that convex hull consists of them.(m <= n)

This takes `O(m*n)` time, see the [Jarvis march](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) algorithm. You need to check that each point is actually part of the convex hull, you can't just extend the elastic band once and be done with it.

Comment: That sentence about "less than `O(n)`" is obviously wrong, but even with `O(n)`, OP is basically saying that step 3. should somehow be magically translated to a constant time running algorithm, which would result in total time lower than the lower bound.

Comment: we do not need to check all points to find out which one is in convex hull . the pines could be objects contatning data we need . like coordinations and ...      that would still take O(n) to put the pins on the board

Comment: @kiyarash - you do for the rubber band algorithm. How else do you suggest to do it?